# Autocomplete tags in dynamic div

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, jquery-autocomplete

Currently i am trying to create tags dynamically on dynamic div.I used this 'http://www.uibox.in/item/16' link to create tags statically,now i am trying to convert this functionality into dynamic divs which is also created in jquery, but i am not able to connect jquery of this link into my dynamic div functionality.

Here is my dynamic div-

```
 var t = $('<div class="imgHover"><div class="hover"><div contenteditable="true" id="autotag"></div></div></div>');

                                    im = $("<img>");
                                    t.append(im);
```

and here i am calling my jquery on click-

```
$("div#autotag").click(function () {

                                   $(document).ready(function () {
                                       var t = $(this).parent().find('div#autotag');
                                       t.tagautocomplete({
                                       source: ['@ann', '@bill', '@casey', '#work', '#finance', '#home'],
                                            character: '@#&',
                                        });

                                      //  $('span#autotag').first().focus();
                                    });
                              });
```

But i am not able to create tags dynamically on dynamic div.Please help me.

Comment: Please share what you have tried...

Comment: I have edited my question.Please view it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean under "create tags dynamically on dynamic div"?

- If it is about filling dynamically autocomplete list you should look at [documentation of jQuery#typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) which is a dependency of bootstrap-tagautocomplete and initialize `source` parameter as a function
- If it is about putting text of tags into edit field you can either insert it like plain text or make it like here [Typeahead.select](https://github.com/Sandglaz/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/blob/master/deps/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L46)